# Select deselect row grid with pointer events UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I would like to select and deselect the grid lines on hover after the pointer pressed event.
I wish I could do it as it happens for example in excel.

Partly the code works when I drag down but if I drag up to the first selected line the selection remains only on one line.

xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="BorderThickness">0,0,0,1</Thickness>
    <Color x:Key="BorderColor">#FFB7B7B7</Color>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="GridDay" Width="200" Height="250" Background="#FFF2F2F2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg0" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg2" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg3" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg4" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg5" Grid.Row="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg6" Grid.Row="6" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg7" Grid.Row="7" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg8" Grid.Row="8" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg9" Grid.Row="9" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Gg10" Grid.Row="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource BorderThickness}" PointerPressed="GridPointerPressed" PointerReleased="GridPointerReleased" PointerEntered="GridPointerEntered" PointerExited="GridPointerExited" Background="Transparent"/>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
    SolidColorBrush selectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    SolidColorBrush deselectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

    bool pressed = false;
    bool selected = false;

    List<Grid> SelectedGrid = new List<Grid>();

    double entered;
    double exited;


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GridPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selected)
        {
            selected = false;
            foreach (Grid grid in SelectedGrid)
            {
                grid.Background = deselectedColor;
            }
            SelectedGrid = new List<Grid>();
        }

        if (!pressed)
        {
            SelectedGrid.Add((Grid)sender);
            ((Grid)sender).Background = selectedColor;
            pressed = true;
        }
    }


    private void GridPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = false;
        selected = true;
    }


    private void GridPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        entered = e.GetCurrentPoint(GridDay).Position.Y;

        if (pressed)
        {
            ((Grid)sender).Background = selectedColor;
            SelectedGrid.Add((Grid)sender);
        }
    }

    private void GridPointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        exited = e.GetCurrentPoint(GridDay).Position.Y;

        bool up = entered > exited;

        if (pressed && up)
        {
            SelectedGrid[SelectedGrid.Count - 1].Background = deselectedColor;
            SelectedGrid.RemoveAt(SelectedGrid.Count - 1);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Partly the code works when I drag down but if I drag up to the first selected line the selection remains only on one line.

The code you post only works for drag down is because the logic that drag down and drag up is different. When you drag up, the up logic should be the opposite of when you drag down.

I changed your code a little bit to correct it. You could take a look at the following code:

```
  double beginposition;

  private void GridPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        beginposition = e.GetCurrentPoint(GridDay).Position.Y;

        PressedGridName = ((Grid)sender).Name;

        if (selected)
        {
            selected = false;
            foreach (Grid grid in SelectedGrid)
            {
                grid.Background = deselectedColor;
            }
            SelectedGrid = new List<Grid>();
        }

        if (!pressed)
        {
            SelectedGrid.Add((Grid)sender);
            ((Grid)sender).Background = selectedColor;
            pressed = true;
        }
    }

  private void GridPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        entered = e.GetCurrentPoint(GridDay).Position.Y;

        //if (pressed)
        //{
        //    ((Grid)sender).Background = selectedColor;
        //    SelectedGrid.Add((Grid)sender);
        //}
    }

    private void RemoveGrid() 
    {
        SelectedGrid[SelectedGrid.Count - 1].Background = deselectedColor;
        SelectedGrid.RemoveAt(SelectedGrid.Count - 1);
    }

    private void AddGrid(object sender) 
    {
        ((Grid)sender).Background = selectedColor;
        SelectedGrid.Add((Grid)sender);
    }

    private void GridPointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        exited = e.GetCurrentPoint(GridDay).Position.Y;

        bool direction = entered > beginposition;


        if (pressed && direction)
        {
            // drag down
            bool up = entered > exited;
            if (pressed && up)
            {
                // prevent it removes the original pressed button
                if (SelectedGrid[SelectedGrid.Count - 1].Name != PressedGridName)
                {
                    RemoveGrid();
                }
               
            }
            else if (pressed && !up)
            {
                AddGrid(sender);
            }
        }
        else if (pressed && !direction) 
        {
            // drag up
            bool up = entered > exited;

            if (pressed && up)
            {
                AddGrid(sender);
            }
            else if (pressed && !up)
            {
                // prevent it removes the original pressed button
                if (SelectedGrid[SelectedGrid.Count - 1].Name != PressedGridName)
                {
                    RemoveGrid();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I added a value called `beginposition` to check if the action is drag up or drag down so that we could use the correct logic to remove and add the grid.